# iOS Observatory not discovered after 30 seconds Flutter after Update Sonoma

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, macos-sonoma

I recently updated MacOS to Sonoma (Version 14.0). Then I have to update the Xcode version to 3.0.

Flutter version: 2.8.1
MacOS version:Sonoma (Version 14.0)
Android Studio Version: Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Xcode version: 3.0.

I'm unable to debug my working app on physical iOS devices It says the "iOS Observatory not discovered after 30 seconds. This is taking much longer than expected..."

Devices tested: iPhone 6, iPhone 12,

The app runs properly on the iOS emulator and Android emulator, but not on the real iOS device.
And also, previously (before the update), I could make a test release on iOS, and it worked properly. Now, when it is installed, it gets a white screen and crashes.

And Android releases and Android emulators are still working fine.

I have tried

- Flutter clean,
- pod Install,
- pod Update,
- Laptop Restart,
- Try running on Xcode.

If anyone faces this issue,
How do I fix this issue ?

If you need more information or have anything that are not in clear, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Flutter is now working as expected with Physical devices in Beta channel, can you please use the beta channel and try!

---

So I will try to give an answer, incomplete by nature, first things first, you have to update flutter then update XCode-tools.

then you HAVE to run your flutter project from inside XCode (This is a must for XCode 15, there is a fix in master for this you can cherry pick  [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133465))

After that you can connect to your the running app for debugging from anywhere be it android studio or vscode through flutter attach comman (you need to specify the device id + app bundle)

Another thing you can do is wait, the issue will be addressed in a hotfix soon..